# How to escape grep and awk within pipe in an alias?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, pipe, alias

I want to  create an alias for an long command. But I'm not able to escape it correct, I guess it's a problem with the pipes.

**My original command**

```
ps aux | grep gimp | awk '{ print $2 '\011' $11 }' | grep -v 'grep'
```

**My attempt for an alias**

```
alias psa="ps aux | grep $1 | awk '{ print \$2 \"\011\" \$11 }' | grep -v 'grep'"
```

But I get an error that `grep` can not open file `foo` (when I do `psa foo`)
When I remove the last part `| grep -v 'grep'` then `awk`throws the same error.

I prefer an alias before an shell script.

Comment: Your original command doesn't look right, shouldn't it be double quotes in the `print` command?

Comment: Aliases don't process arguments, so I don't think what you're doing will work even if you solve the quoting problem. Make it a shell function.

Comment: why do you parse the output of `ps` like this? it's terrible! Don't you just mean `pgrep -l gimp`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a function if you want to to insert arguments:

```
psa() {
    ps aux | grep "$1" | awk '{print $2 "\t" $11 }' | grep -v grep
}
```

Comment: You don't need all those pipes and commands, one awk command would do it: `ps aux | awk -v cmd="$1" '($0~cmd)&&($0!~"grep"){print $2 "\t" $11 }'`. Not saying it's the right approach overall, just abbreviating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all the escaping by using a function for this:

```
myps() {
   ps aux | grep gimp | awk '{ print $2 "\011" $11 }' | grep -v 'grep'
}
```